# Firebase .getDownloadURL() returns undefined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I created function which on form submit to upload picture to Firebase storage.

The function is uploading the img successfuly but can't retrieve the proper url. It is returning 'undefined' for url property

function:

```
   constructor(
         public dbStorage: AngularFireStorage, 
    ) { }

Upload(event$) {
    this.selectedImg = $event.target.files[0];

    const car = {
                  photoURL: `/images/cars/${new 
                    Date().getTime()}-${this.selectedImg.name.split('.').slice(0,-1)}`,
                  photo: this.selectedImg,  
                  }
    const _photoURL = this.dbStorage.ref(car.photoURL);
    this.dbStorage.upload(car.photoURL, car.photo).snapshotChanges().pipe(
         finalize(()=>{
             _photoURL.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) =>{
               car.photoURL = url;
            })
         })
    ).subscribe();
}
```